# Java XChart: Подпись точек линии

Tags: java, gui, диаграммы

Возможно ли создание подписей на точках графика, построенных при помощи библиотеки `XChart`.

Т.е. мне надо нарисовать что-то вроде шкалы масштаба.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеющиеся точки подписать, например, 10, 100, 500. А как это сделать не могу понять.

```
chrGraph.getStyleManager().setYAxisMin(yLow);
chrGraph.getStyleManager().setYAxisMax(yHigh);
for (int i = 0; i < rpData.length; i ++){
   z[i]= Calc.rpScaleCalc(rpData[i]);
   y[i]=0;
}
Series sc = chrGraph.addSeries("Scale", z, y);
```